# 42000 [SQLSTATE] [Microsoft] [ODBC 17 driver for SQL Server] [SQL Server] It is not possible to open the database "

Tags: php, connection

I'm using SqlServer 2019 and Php and I'm trying to connect to my database but I got the following error:

> 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4060 [code] => 4060 [2] =>
> [Microsoft] [ODBC 17 driver for SQL Server] [SQL Server] It is not
> possible to open the database ""  requested by the 'login. Login
> failed. [message] => [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] [SQL
> Server] Cannot open database "" requested by login. Login failed. ))

My code to connect to the database is:

```
try{  
    $dbName = "GestonePreventiviDB";
    $serverName = "localhost";  //serverName\instanceName

    // Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
    // The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$dbName);
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo,);

    if( $conn ) {
        echo "Conessione effettuata <br />";
    }else{
        echo "Impossibile stabilire una connessione.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

}

catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Errore connessione<br>".$e->getMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "General Error: errore<br>".$e->getMessage();
}
```

On the Pc where I create the database it works but when I tried to copy on my desktop I got the error. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo,);
```

Into:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

> Without the comma at end.